# Need help in time conversions JS or PHP

Tags: javascript, php, timezone, momentjs

This is the scenario i have time at Tues 2017-04-05 13:30 in Asia/Hong_Kong

A user in America/Chicago enters the site see the above time date to

which becomes to 2017-04-05 00:30 // which is -13 hours from 13:30

After weeks of frustration to find something this is what i got

```
function convertIt(time){
  var currentzone = Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone;//get America/Chicago
  var currentday = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD"); //2017-04-05
  var AsiaHour = "13:30";
  var full = currentday+"T"+AsiaHour;
  var to = moment(full).tz('Asia/Hong_Kong').format('dddd HH:mm');
  alert(to); //prints Friday 02:30 Which adds +13 and do the opposite
};
```

I checked many of the answers over those related questions on here but i couldn't do it and they were in node.js

The above is example for HongKong to Chicago, but i am aim for different timezones to different usertimes

Please help me find what i am missing and **do not** respond with node js solutions, PHP is accepted thanks very much

Comment: I would store all your date/time values in UTC, so if a client sends a time, they send a UTC time.  Then, when showing date/times to clients you are just converting from UTC to their local timezone.

Comment: can you give me example of UTC storing values and conversion method/function ?

Comment: Javascript can convert a time in the user's local timezone to UTC using `theDate.toUTCString()`, which you could then store in the database as UTC.  When a client requests this data, send them the UTC time and use `theDate = new Date(utcDate);` to convert it to user's time zone.

Comment: so if var theDate = 'Thursday 13:30'; i should use theDate.toUTCString() function to convert date to UTC first ? then i should use new Date(utcDate) where utcDate is the first theDate but in UTC right?

Comment: @mohamedtebry did you asked the same question a while ago and then deleted it? If yes, please note that this practice is [discouraged](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320782/4131048) and may lead to question ban. Please use edits to add details to your questions and bounty to bring attention on them.

Comment: yes i did sorry didnt know i messed up, please dont remove my question i really need help since this is related to my graduation project

Comment: @mohamedtebry - Sorry, but it's a bit rude to show only JavaScript in your question and then demand that one only give a PHP answer.  Show us what you have tried in PHP.  The code is much different between the two.  There are plenty of PHP questions related to time zones, and the PHP docs on this are quite good.  Also, recognize that no matter how important the question is for you, that has no bearing on how you should act here, or what you should expect in response.  Everyone here has to play by the same rules.  Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: i asked for not to post node js but php javascript is fine since node js requires different server did not mean that javascript is not allowed my code is in javascript so

Answer (score 1):

You can save the time in UTC, like:

```
var time = moment.utc(new Date());
```

and then retrieve it in local time, like:

```
var convertedTime = moment(time);
```

Comment: moment.utc thats nodejs? in js it should be moment().utc? Also i dont want to store current time i want to pass certain specific times

Comment: It is js. For hardcoding the time, use something like this: var time = moment.utc('2013-01-01T00:00:00-13:00');

Comment: sorry i dont get it, how to use this function for my conversion?

Comment: Your time is 2017-04-05 13:30 in HongKong local time, and HongKong time zone has an offset of +8:00 hours. So when you are saving your time, you should save it as: var time = moment.utc('2017-04-05 13:30:00+8:00').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'); and then get it back in localTime as: var localTime  = moment(moment.utc(time).toDate()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

Comment: Not working; says Invalid Date, maybe your code is right since i need to save var time first in database once Hong/Kong client uses it first, but it doesnt work when i test it, i need to perform tests to get accurate results, also what if a person just puts tuesday - 13:30  and puts another date wednesday 18:30 which he didnt provide a certain day date just week day?

Comment: The code should work as long as you have moment.js. It has a minor format issue that you can fix with the following code: var time = moment.utc('2017-04-05 13:30:00+08:00'); I just added a 0 before 8. I am not sure if I got what you meant for the second question.

Comment: in my second question i meant to say that if HongKong user added only tuesday - 13:30 as the date he provides without 2017-04-05 and ofc tuesday is not 2017-04-05, how this would be possible to be converted? with only (zone provided and weekday and hour) without (yyyy-mm-dd)

Comment: First please endorse my answer if it was helpful, then we can move on to your next question. Thank you.

Comment: You can use the following piece of code: moment().day("Tuesday").hour(13).minute(30).second(0)